# Neo4j 3.0.1 - org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm moving from SDN 3 to SDN 4 and from Neo4j 2.3 to 3.0.1

Right now my test fails on the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} WITH vg MATCH vg-[:CONTAINS]->(v:Vote)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(u) = {userId} RETURN v
```

with a following exception:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:176)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.execute(EmbeddedRequest.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.executeAndMap(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:110)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.queryForObject(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:56)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.queryForObject(Neo4jSession.java:308)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.findVoteForDecisionOnCriterionByAuthorId(Unknown Source
```

This query works fine on Neo4j 2.3

What can be a reason of that and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because Neo4j 3 does not like bare nodes any more. I changed `MATCH vg` to `MATCH (vg)`:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} 
WITH vg 
MATCH (vg)-[:CONTAINS]->(v:Vote)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(u) = {userId} 
RETURN v
```